# Is it possible for a dart package to have a dependency on a private repository hosted by bitbucket?

Tags: dart, flutter, bitbucket

Is it possible to have a package that references a private bitbucket repository?  Something like below but I would need to supply a password and username.  Is this at all possible with Dart?

```
dependencies:  
  secreterepo:
    git: https://blah@bitbucket.org/blah/secretrepo.git
```

Comment: You could set up SSH to create an authenticated connection to BitBucket and then use an SSH URL in the dependency like `git@bitbucket.org:blah/secretrepo.git`

Comment: Many thanks @GünterZöchbauer that works well :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up SSH to create an authenticated connection to BitBucket and then use an SSH URL in the dependency like `git@bitbucket.org:blah/secretrepo.git`

Comment: A link for anyone wanting to setup a bitbucket SSH key https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html